# Can I safely remove my USB drive when my machine is suspended?

Tags: mount, usb-drive, suspend

I often suspend my laptop with a USB drive still mounted. What I would like to do is store my laptop away and of course, the USB drive is in the way. So I was thinking of removing the USB drive and then storing the laptop. Before I turn the laptop back on, I would insert the drive again. Assuming I don't forget to put the USB drive back in, is there any risk in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It should work **flawlessly** if you don't forget to plug the drive again before resuming the computer.
In case you forget to plug in the external USB drive, then you could get an **error** or **undefined behavior** of the program(s) that were tracking and using your drive before suspending the computer.